# I want to list my arrayList in a special shape

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList and I want to list it in a special shape. Those number exist in the arraylist and arraylist has 20 3 times.

```
+--------+--------+  
| Number | Occurs |   
+--------+--------+  
|      20|       3|   
+--------+--------+  
|      15|       2|  
+--------+--------+  
|      12|       3|  
+--------+--------+  
|       4|       1|  
+--------+--------+  
|       3|       3|   
+--------+--------+
```

The above shape that I want. I couldn't make up smoothly but boxes stand on the bottom of the other one and that's following my method.

```
public void list() {

    System.out.println("+-------+-------+");
    System.out.println("+ number+ occurs+");
    for (int i = 0; i < arry.size(); i++) {
        if (arry.get(i) > 0) {
            System.out.println("+-------+-------+");
            fmt = new Formatter();
            fmt.format("|%7d||%7d|", i,arry.get(i));
            System.out.println(fmt);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("+-------+-------+");
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get your problem, can you post the wrong results you get?

Comment: I'm not willing to spend any time helping you with a formatting issue.  Get a shovel and start digging.

Comment: You seem to just print the index and value instead of the value and occurrences. You should first collect the data in the list into a frequency map, then print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer below fixes the formatting of the table. it does not concern the calculation of occurences in the array (since this was not the question)

```
System.out.println("+-------+-------+");
System.out.println("| number| occurs|");
for (int i = 0; i < arry.size(); i++) {
    if (arry.get(i) > 0) {
        System.out.println("+-------+-------+");
        System.out.println(String.format("|%7d|%7d|", i,arry.get(i)));
    }
}
System.out.println("+-------+-------+");
```